# How to return a custom headers with Retry-After in SvelteKit api/something/+server.js?

Tags: javascript, sveltekit

I'm using SvelteKit `api/getinfo/+server.js` and trying to return a `Retry-After` header.

```js
export async function POST(requestEvent){
    // some code that is irrelevant  to my question.
    return new Response({status : 429, Retry-After : 60})
}
```

I get error with Parse failure. Can't find After
I looked the header name [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After) and it is the right name so maybe my syntax is wrong. How do I return the status : 429 and Retry-After : 60 (60 is for 60 seconds)

Comment: You can't use `-` in an unquoted JSON property.  You want `"Retry-After" : 60`.  That said, I don't think that's how you add headers.  I believe there's an object assigned to the `headers` property of that object (or possibly like that as a scond argument)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to use JSON.stringify() and see if it works.